# Thermostatic shower valve with tankless gas heaters

Tags: shower, bathroom-fixtures

Are there any benefits to using thermostatic shower valves when my tankless gas heathers already limits its maximum temperature at 48°C (it can only reacho more up to 65° by disabling the safety feature).

This heater modulates the flame so that the output temperature is near constant. I understand that if something sudenly draws cold water the temperature might rise, but I doubt it would me much of a concern.

Thermostatic valves are more expensive, bigger (two dials vs a single monocomand mixer) and its replacement cartdrige is much more expensive than a regular one.

Comment: What country are you in?  Many building codes specify that shower valves _must_ be the thermostatic type.  Are you sure you can install a non-temperature control valve

Comment: Brazil, no restriction here. I might go with the thermostatic if it offers me some advantage. Scalding is no concern, I usually have the heater set near to the temperature that we bathe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than scald prevention, which isn't much of a concern with 48°C water, the other "features" are being able to set a maximum temperature, and attempting to maintain temperature when the pressure on one side dips.

Since you say that you set the heater near your bathing temperature, then it sounds like those other features won't do much for you since you're using almost 100% hot water rather than a mixture of hot and cold.

I don't set my water heater much higher than yours, but I still like the ability to adjust the maximum temperature in my kids bathroom.  I have it set where it doesn't even get hot enough for me to take a good shower, but its perfect for their bath and can't get hotter than they would like.

Comment: The valve model I'm looking at has a preset at 38ºC (you press a red button to be able to set it hotter), it costs double what a single shower mixer costs. Anyway, it seems that it keeps the temperature much more stable than I can get with my heater. I'm ordering them for the two shower :)